# Проблема при воспроизведении видео с использванием библиотеки android-youtube-player

Tags: android, youtube, видео, мобильная-разработка, youtube-android-api

Я хочу воспроизвести видео. Для этого воспользовалься [библиотекой](https://github.com/PierfrancescoSoffritti/android-youtube-player#android-youtube-player).

Добавил в активити необходимый view

```
<com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer.core.player.views.YouTubePlayerView
            android:id="@+id/yt_pl1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:autoPlay="false"
            app:showFullScreenButton="true"
            app:showYouTubeButton="true"
            app:videoId="y3bW3H95NMw" />
```

В gradle добавил необходимый зависимость

```
implementation 'com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer:core:10.0.5'
```

**Проблема в том что в видео есть звук но нет картины.**

*Прощу строго не ругать, я только начинаю программировать.*

Comment: Странно, только что создал чистый активити с плеером и у меня есть как звук, так и картинка. Писали ли вы какой-то код для плеера в актиити? Может, XML верстка плохо создана?

Comment: @AdisAlagic а вы воспользовались библиотекой на которую я ссылался?
я старался делать все как на видеоруководствах, хмл как у них. обычно в хмл добавляли только айди от видео в  view YouTubePlayerView.